# how to create file txt filename from file csv with python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

```
import csv
with open("HORSES.csv") as f:
for row in csv.reader(f):   
    # Number of pages plus one
    for horse in row:
        print (horse)
with open("%s.txt" % horse, "w") as f:
            f.close()
```

this content file horses.csvwest,usa,asia,black. output os fine ok, but for create .txt file only black.txt end of file horses.csv not create file txt from list pd csv file, how to create .txt file with filename from list file horses.csv like this west.txt usa.txt asia.txt black.txt

Answer (score 0):

Your last `with` statement is not part of a loop, so you'll only get the last value stored in `horse`.

If you want multiple .txt files, put them in a loop and create them one at a time:

```
import csv

Horse_types = []

with open("HORSES.csv") as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):   
        for horse in row:
            print (horse)
            Horse_types.append(horse)

for ht in Horse_types:
    with open("%s.txt" % ht, "w") as f:
        # More stuff here?
        f.close()
```

Comment: thanks .,can you help me again for full my code? above code part of script with beatifulsoup because iam always getting error